How can I create a bootable USB stick with OS X 10.15.7?
I'm trying to create a bootable USB stick with the Apple Hardware Test for my MacBook Pro 13" mid 2012 (MacBookPro9,2)
I used the instructions here, but it seems that the USB Stick I get is not bootable.
https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest?tab=readme-ov-file
In fact, if I right-click Information in Hard Disk Utility, it lists "bootable: no" and if I try to boot and hold the option key, the usb drive is not listed there, but I do not see how I could change this...
Here is the info from Disk Utility about the USB stick - "startfähig" (="bootable") -> "Nein" (no)

And here is the verbose output of the bless command
sudo bless --folder /Volumes/USBstick/ --file /Volumes/USBstick/System/Library/CoreServices/.diagnostics/diags.efi --label AHT --verbose          
Password:
EFI found at IODeviceTree:/efi
Mount point for /Volumes/USBstick/ is /Volumes/USBStick
Common mount point of '/Volumes/USBstick/' and '' is /Volumes/USBStick
No BootX creation requested
This is not an APFS Data-Volume-Parameter-Driven Pre-SSV to SSV case
No boot.efi creation requested
Refitting to width 23
Refitting to width 47
Scale 1 label data is valid: YES
Putting scale 1 label bitmap in /Volumes/USBstick//.disk_label
Deleting old /Volumes/USBstick//.disk_label
Opened dest at /Volumes/USBstick//.disk_label for writing
0x00001000 bytes preallocated for /Volumes/USBstick//.disk_label

Type/creator set to tbxj/chrp for /Volumes/USBstick//.disk_label
Scale 1 label written
Invisibility set for /Volumes/USBstick//.disk_label
Putting scale 2 label bitmap in /Volumes/USBstick//.disk_label_2x
Deleting old /Volumes/USBstick//.disk_label_2x
Opened dest at /Volumes/USBstick//.disk_label_2x for writing
0x00001000 bytes preallocated for /Volumes/USBstick//.disk_label_2x

Scale 2 label written
Invisibility set for /Volumes/USBstick//.disk_label_2x
Got directory ID of 2 for /Volumes/USBstick/
Got file ID of 388 for /Volumes/USBstick/System/Library/CoreServices/.diagnostics/diags.efi
finderinfo[0] = 2
finderinfo[1] = 388
finderinfo[2] = 0
finderinfo[3] = 0
finderinfo[5] = 2

Here is the output of bless --info for the USBstick:
bless --info USBStick                                     
finderinfo[0]:      2 => Blessed System Folder is /Volumes/USBStick/
finderinfo[1]:    388 => Blessed System File is /Volumes/USBStick/System/Library/CoreServices/.diagnostics/diags.efi
finderinfo[2]:      0 => Open-folder linked list empty
finderinfo[3]:      0 => No alternate OS blessed file/folder
finderinfo[4]:      0 => Unused field unset
finderinfo[5]:      2 => OS X blessed folder is /Volumes/USBStick/
64-bit VSDB volume id:  0x15DE27667AD09506


Have you created the boot drive with GUID partition scheme?

yes, I have - I did everything according to the instructions on the linked github page, but the usb stick is not bootable (neither is it listed in the startup volume system preferences) - I'll add more info to my question
